# MATLAB: Specify Simulink simulation time using code

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want to run Simulink simulation from a script, and I can do it using:

```
sim('MobileRobotSimulation')
```

However, I would like to specify the time of the simulation. I wonder how I can achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found in this [link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/40457-set-simulink-model-simulation-stop-time-from-m-file), it is possible to specify the simulation time using the following code:

```
set_param(model_name, 'StopTime', '20')
```

so in this case the simulation time is 20 seconds, and  `model_name = 'MobileRobotSimulation'`.

Comment: Consider also to give "Stop Time" within the simulation configuration pane a variable and specify that in workspace.

Comment: Thank you @thewaywewalk, I will consider this option too.

Comment: You can also pass 'StopTime' as a parameter for the call to sim.